# Pass Twilio SMS Post Data from Node to React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, twilio

I'm currently using Twilio to receive SMS messages on my server. I need to display the return data in React. Twilio only sends the data server side through a POST request. If I send a text from my phone. The Twilio POST request will be send the data to my server.  How can I get the POST data sent to my React app? The below code is how I receive the data from Twilio.

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {

var msgFrom = req.body.From;
var msgBody = req.body.Body;})
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can and there are two ways:

1- you can use the the HTTP regular request model, you can achieve this by sending a request checking for updates and if there is what and update the front end.

2- long polling or streams sockets to emit the data to your applications from the back end.